# Confusing use of 'up to'

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

> You can cancel the tickets up to thirty minutes before the scheduled departure of the train.

Is the use of 'up to'semantically correct? Or, is 'at least' more appropriate to replace 'up to'?

Should it be rewritten to make the sense clearer in following manner?

> You can cancel the tickets any time but at least thirty minutes before the scheduled departure of the train.

Comment: "Any time but at least thirty minutes before" sounds humorously convoluted. As if "any time" can only take place within those thirty minutes before, e.g. "you can go to heaven any time but at least when you die."

Comment: I"d change "up to" to "until".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, "up to" is ambiguous if taken literally. Those who would argue otherwise fail to see that their understanding is predicated on their knowledge of the context of the statement.

Take for instance, the following two sentences which use "up to" for diametrically opposing representations of time:

1. You can cancel the tickets up to thirty minutes before the
   scheduled departure of the train.
2. EA Play access is usually granted up to 1 week before release.

In the first example, "up to" means "as ***late*** as". In the second example, "up to" means "as ***early*** as".

In the first, "up to" and "before" denote the ***minimum*** amount of time before the event (30 minutes). In the second, the same words "up to" and "before" denote the ***maximum*** amount of time before the event (1 week).

"As late as" and "as early as" are just as succinct as "up to" and they have the added advantage of being unambiguous. Unfortunately, "up to" is used more often.

Comment: In the train ticket example "up to" is only ambiguous if context is deliberately ignored,, which nobody buying tickets would do.

Comment: @nnnnnn Understanding of the intention of the speaker varies, so it isn't true that the context is being "ignored". Another example is that when I buy plane tickets, I receive an email saying that I can preorder my meals up to 24 hours before the flight. Do they require at least 24 hours to prepare the meal, or do I need to wait till one day before the flight in order for them to have the menus ready (after knowing who to cater for and how)? Both are logical assumptions and taking one interpretation or the other does not ignore the context.

Answer (score 1):

> You can cancel the tickets **up to thirty minutes before** the scheduled departure of the train.

Here "up to" means time going forwards or "until".

> You can cancel the tickets **any time but at least thirty minutes before** the scheduled departure of the train.

Which is it? "any time" or "at least thirty minutes before"? It says one thing then immediately contradicts itself. People don't always have time to struggle through complex grammar when they need an answer to the question "Can I cancel my ticket right now?" This is a real world problem, not a thought experiment. The simplest grammar is preferable.

Comment: Yes, the simplest grammar is preferable in our daily life, if not in the legal construction.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the use of 'up to' semantically correct?

Yes.

> Or, is 'at least' more appropriate to replace 'up to'?

No.

> Should it be rewritten to clear the sense in following manner?

No.

up - adverb = upwards (indicating an advance motion, place or time.)

to - preposition

to + substantive  = modifier.

Up to + substantive = adverb.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, 'up to' can be parsed as follows:

> (1) You can cancel the tickets [up to [thirty minutes before the scheduled departure of the train]].

> (2) You can cancel the tickets [[up to thirty minutes] before the scheduled departure of the train].

(1) is the normal reading in context, and (2) is an alternative reading which is possible but nonsensical. Since most people would parse the sentence like (1), there should be little confusion as long as context is as clear as here.

To replace 'up to' with 'at least' in the sentence would make it sound a bit strange, if not ungrammatical, perhaps due to the combination of 'can cancel' and 'at least thirty minutes'.

> (3) ?You can cancel the tickets [[at least thirty minutes] before the scheduled departure of the train].

Using 'at least' might work in a slightly different sentence:

> (3') If you're to cancel the tickets, you must cancel them [[at least thirty minutes] before the scheduled departure of the train].